# MVC, Jquery: Trying to send a hashtable to a MVC controller

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, hashtable

I have a hashtable, which contains the following data

```
[248] = "18,19",
[250] = "1,2,3",
[254] = "06/06/2013",
[271] = "AAA",
[331] = "1"
```

// converting it to JSON serializable data the data is as follows

```
  var dataTosend = '{ jsonData:' + JSON.stringify(dictData) + '}';
  //Output is as follows
  {jsonData: {"248":"18,19","250":"1,2,3","254":"06/06/2013","271":"AAA","331":"1"}}
```

// Ajax call

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/GridSearch/FetchDataForAjaxCall',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            datatype: 'json',
            data: dataTosend,
            traditional: true,
            success: function (data) {
                myData = data;
                grid = new Slick.Grid("#teamGrid", myData, columns, options);
                grid.autosizeColumns();

            },
            error: function (y)
            {   alert(y.responseText);
            }
        })
```

//part of the controller's action

```
public JsonResult FetchDataForAjaxCall(string jsonData)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonData))
   {
    JsonResult jsResult = new JsonResult();
    jsResult = Json("Null Data Received", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    return jsResult;            
    }

 }
```

The controller receives null, I do understand I would need to deserialize data etc. 
However I always get back a null value.
I did try and change jsondata to a string and the controller received the same. 
However I am sure I am missing a step with the hashtable.

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Could someone provide me with a working solution?

Thanks

Comment: You set var dataTosend but use sdata variable in the $.ajax call?

Comment: Hello Yeronimo, that was a typo error in the code snippet I was submitting. thanks for spotting it. However the problem is that the controller parameter jsonData receives null.

Comment: You are doing an ajax POST and your action is a GET..

Comment: If you did : [HttpPost]public JsonResult FetchDataForAjaxCall(FormCollection form). You could then get the contents from : form["jsonData"]

Comment: Hello Steve, I have tried your suggestion .. however no luck.

Comment: And what if you match up the controller action's parametername?
So either from jQuery not send data, but jsonData: dataTosend
Or change it in controller:
    public JsonResult FetchDataForAjaxCall(string data)